# Java ExecutorService slower than serial in when using ArrayList is it ?

Tags: java, arraylist, parallel-processing, executorservice

I am trying to split a big list into two tasks and perform some processing and later merge them. In the below test, i found out serial processing is lot faster than parallel (or) am i doing something wrong.
Below is the result,

`sh-4.3$ java -Xmx128M -Xms16M FutureTaskDemo`

```
I =2  
Sequential Result         : 2000000 calculated in 2339 ms 
First Value:2 List Value:2000001                          
Initial List First Value:2 List Value:2000001             
I =1000004                                                
I =4  
1000000
1000000                                                   
Merging                                                   
Parallel Result         : 2000000 calculated in 3207 ms   
First Value:4 List Value:2000003
```

Below is the code,

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.FutureTask;

public class FutureTaskDemo {

/**
 * Maximum amount of numbers to check
 */
public static final int MAX_NUMBER = 2_000_000;

public static List<Integer> addOneToListS(List<Integer> list) {
Integer flag=0;
for(Integer i = 0;i<list.size();i++)
{
    if(flag==0) System.out.println("I ="+(list.get(i)+2));
   list.set(i, list.get(i) +2);
   flag=1;
}

    return list;
}

public static List<Integer> addOneToListP(List<Integer> list)
        throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {

    List<Integer> listA = new ArrayList<>(list.subList(0,MAX_NUMBER/2));
    List<Integer> listB = new ArrayList<>(list.subList(MAX_NUMBER/2,MAX_NUMBER));

    // Prepare to execute and store the Futures
    int threadNum = 2;
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadNum);
    List<FutureTask<List<Integer>>> taskList = new ArrayList<FutureTask<List<Integer>>>();

    // Start thread for the first half of the numbers
    FutureTask<List<Integer>> futureTask_1 = new FutureTask<List<Integer>>(new Callable<List<Integer>>() {
        @Override
        public List<Integer> call() {
            return FutureTaskDemo.addOneToListS(listA);
        }
    });
    taskList.add(futureTask_1);
    executor.execute(futureTask_1);

    // Start thread for the second half of the numbers
    FutureTask<List<Integer>> futureTask_2 = new FutureTask<List<Integer>>(new Callable<List<Integer>>() {
        @Override
        public List<Integer> call() {
            return FutureTaskDemo.addOneToListS(listB);
        }
    });
    taskList.add(futureTask_2);
    executor.execute(futureTask_2);

    // Wait until all results are available and combine them at the same time
Integer totalsize = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < threadNum; j++) {
        FutureTask<List<Integer>> futureTask = taskList.get(j);
        System.out.println(futureTask.get().size());
    }
    executor.shutdown();
    System.out.println("Merging");
    List<Integer> fullList = new ArrayList<>();
    fullList.addAll(futureTask_1.get());
    fullList.addAll(futureTask_2.get());

    return fullList;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {

    // Sequential execution
List<Integer> initialList = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i=0;i<MAX_NUMBER;i++)
    initialList.add(i);

    long timeStart = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
    List<Integer> addedList1 = FutureTaskDemo.addOneToListS(initialList);
    long timeEnd = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
    long timeNeeded = timeEnd - timeStart;
    System.out.println("Sequential Result         : " + addedList1.size()+ " calculated in " + timeNeeded + " ms");
    System.out.println("First Value:"+addedList1.get(0)+" List Value:"+addedList1.get(addedList1.size()-1));

    System.out.println("Initial List First Value:"+initialList.get(0)+" List Value:"+initialList.get(initialList.size()-1));
     timeStart = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
    List<Integer> addedList2 = FutureTaskDemo.addOneToListP(initialList);
     timeEnd = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
     timeNeeded = timeEnd - timeStart;
    System.out.println("Parallel Result         : " + addedList2.size()+ " calculated in " + timeNeeded + " ms");
    System.out.println("First Value:"+addedList2.get(0)+" List Value:"+addedList2.get(addedList2.size()-1));


}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use parallel streams

```
public static List<Integer> addOneToListP(List<Integer> list) {
    return list.parallelStream().map(i -> i + 1).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

This is a lot shorter, simpler and easier to understand.  Whether it is any faster, will depend on whether what you are doing is sped up by having more CPUs or the overhead of using multiple threads and passing data between them is too high. Your parallel version is doing a lot of copying around of the data.

You biggest overhead is likely to be the very high rate of garbage you are creating.  I would see what happens with a collection without so much garbage.

```
public static int[] addOneToListP(int[] array) {
    return IntStream.of(array).parallel().map(i -> i + 1).toArray();
}
```

This should use a fraction of the memory and be quite a bit faster, with or without multiple CPUs.

Note: your `addOneToListS` appears to add `2` which is confusing.

Comment: Thank You very much peter for answering.

In the above program, adding 2 is the only processing i am doing currently. 

Tried using parallel streams, results were similar. Primitive Integer arrays works very fast.

Since this is a exercise iam doing to see if parallelism is better, when i changed the MAX_NUMBERS to 10million, results still show serial processing is better.

My original problem is, i have around 50k internal html links in a list and to scan and find & keywords used or not. Serial processing is very slow. so, i thought of splitting up list 32ways as 32 cores were available.

Comment: @bobby.dreamer the cost of shifting data between threads is non trivial. In the html links example, the cost of passing the URL is trivial by comparison to the cost of the HTTP request so you should see a good speed up.  Ask you will be spending a lot time waiting for the requests, you might find that 32 cores can handle 64 threads easily esp with hyperthreading and perhaps even 100 or 200 threads depending on how much of the time they spend waiting.